# Variable retrieve JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have de next objet jSon:

{"prtg-version":"14.3.10.2422","treesize":3700,"":[{"objid":0,"probe":"","probe_raw":""}]}

I need the parametres to objid and prove and the next programm javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
            /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
          function act()
        {
            $.getJSON('https://10.213.8.25/api/table.json?columns=objid', function(data) {
                    /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {


                              $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.objid +' </li>');

                    });

                    });
            });


        }
        setInterval(act, 1000);
    });
```

if modifique my jSon all ok:

[{"objid":0,"probe":"","probe_raw":""}]

but the URL works with the before jSon and my programm javascrip and does not work can you help me to comment on the error?

Thank!

Comment: Looks like you should be able to access the array with `data['']`. I'd use a better key though.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following JSON:

```
{
    "prtg-version":"14.3.10.2422",
    "treesize":3700,
    "":[{"objid":0,"probe":"","probe_raw":""}]
}
```

... I would first point out that it's highly unusual to have an empty string (`""`) as a JSON key. That being said, you *can* do that if you want.  If you want to iterate over those values, though, you need to replace:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
```

... with this:

```
$.each(data[""], function(key, val) {
```

Comment: {"prtg-version":"14.3.10.2422","treesize":3188,"sensors":[{"objid":1001}]}   and the function is   $.each(data["sensors"], function(key, val) {
                                $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.objid +' </li>');
                                
                        });   but not work

Answer (score 0):

I still have problems, I have armed the JSON object in PHP and call control and it works but by changing the URL address where you should get your information does not throw me anything you know if I make any changes?

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
            /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
          function act()
        {
            $.getJSON("https://10.213.8.25/api/table.json?&content=sensors&output=json&columns=objid&count=1&username=prtgadmin&password=SIEoperaciones01", function(data) {
            //$.getJSON('DMS_PRTG_prueba.php', function(data) { ***OK***

                    /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.objid +' </li>');

                    });
            });


        }
        setInterval(act, 1000);
    });
```

{"prtg-version":"14.3.10.2422","treesize":3188,"sensors":[{"objid":1001}]}

Comment: You should not update your *question* by *adding an answer*; instead *edit* your question!